# Using qsort to sort an array of structs in C

Tags: c, qsort

I tried to sort an array of Products by its unit price but the result doesn't work.

```
typedef struct {
    int supply;
    int totalPrice;
    double unitPrice;
} Product;

int comparator(const void * a, const void * b) {
    return (*(Product*) b).unitPrice - (*(Product*) a).unitPrice;
}

int main() {
    Product m[3] = {
        {18, 75, 4.17},
        {15, 72, 4.80},
        {10, 45, 4.50}
    };
    qsort(m, 3, sizeof(Product), comparator);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("unitPrice=%f\n", m[i].unitPrice);
    }
}
```

Comment: Editing your question to also show the output would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a `double` value from a function which returns `int` type value, will result in implicit conversion of `double` to `int` and the fractional part will be discarded from returned value.

If you are using `gcc` compiler, try compiling with `-Wconversion` option, the compiler will give warning:

```
 warning: implicit conversion turns floating-point number into integer: 'double' to 'int' [-Wfloat-conversion]
    return (*(Product*) b).unitPrice - (*(Product*) a).unitPrice;
    ~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

You can do:

```
int comparator(const void * a, const void * b) {
    double first = (*(Product*) a).unitPrice;
    double second = (*(Product*) b).unitPrice;

    if (second > first) {
        return 1;
    } else if (second < first) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0; // second == first
}
```

Comment: It is always a code smell to compare floating point values on equality (implicitly done here) without any tolerance. I would define something like `static const double TOLERANCE = 0.005;` and then `(second > first + TOLERANCE)` and `(second < first - TOLERANCE)`.

Answer (score 2):

`comparator` is broken. It subtracts two `double` values and returns an `int`. Any fraction in the subtraction result is lost, so numbers less than one unit apart will be considered equal.

Fix it to return a non-zero number if the items differ.